# Junit test scenario doesn't perform rollback

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions

I have the following test where I need to show that my transaction works and can do rollback. The problem here is  my RuntimeException is executed before the data is entered into the database. So rollback doesn't happen. How do I set up this test?

```
@Test
@Rollback(true)
public void testForTransactionRollback() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("Ivan");
    user.setLastName("Ivanov");
    user.setPhoneNumber("18000000");
    user.setEmail("mail@gmail.com");
    user.setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
    user.setDeliveryAddress("address");
    user.setComment("comment");

    String result = "";

    final ClientDAO clientDao1 = Mockito.spy(new ClientDAOImpl());

    final ClientDAOImpl clientDaoImpl = (ClientDAOImpl) clientDao1;

    Mockito.when(clientDao1.insert(user)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

    try {
        clientDao1.insert(user);
    } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Expected failure to trigger transaction caught");
    } finally {
        user = clientDao1.get(1L);
        if (user != null) {
            result = user.getFirstName();
        }
    }
    Assert.assertEquals("it should be equal", "", result);
}
```

Comment: Why is your test case annotated with `Rollback(true)`? I'm assuming you want to test an actual method in your production code, otherwise this test will actually prove nothing other than your test being able to perform a rollback. You should call your method responsible for handling the transaction, ensure that it fails and then assert that nothing was updated in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're facing is caused by two inner transactions (one inside the other): first one is inside `clientDao1.insert(user)` and a second one inside your test (providing that you annotated your test class with `@Transactional` or `@DataJpaTest`, but you've not shown that). If `RuntimeException` is thrown within inner transaction, which is the case because of

```java
Mockito.when(clientDao1.insert(user)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

then it means your inner `clientDao1.insert` method cannot recover from that exception and the outer method (test one) has nothing to say.

That's why data will NEVER be written to the database or even persisted (hibernate caching, of course if you use hibernate as your JPA provider).